# Raspberry Pi: External HDD "wrong fs type, bad option"

Tags: filesystems, partition

I'm trying to set up an external hard drive to my Pi. I got one from the store with 2TB of storage. I plugged it in and ran `lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 38.8M  1 loop /snap/certbot/1344
loop1         7:1    0 38.7M  1 loop /snap/certbot/1435
loop2         7:2    0 84.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11610
loop3         7:3    0 51.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/1085
sda           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
```

I tried to mount it to `/var/www/drive2` but I got this error:

```
mount: /var/www/drive2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How can I fix this? Is there something wrong with my HDD?

Comment: You have to create some partitions and file systems on it first. Large disks don't come preformatted with a single partition and a FAT filesystem on it, the way USB sticks do.

Comment: First create partition table and format your partition(s) in `sda`

Comment: Does the drive have its own power supply? RPi-USB connectors are not meant to run external drives and your device might just die once more data is tried to be read.